# How do I get my data back from a typescript callback?

Tags: angular, typescript, callback

I am used to use callbacks in javascript, but only just started learning Angular and typescript, so I am not quite sure how to get it working.
This is my code so far. The callback actually works. As it is outputting, my console.log in the correct order, which means the callback is working.
However I need to get my data out of the service back to where I am consoling Finished. I am not sure of the correct format to do this. I have googled for an answer,but not found the correct combination. I am sending my data back with Callback(data), but I don't know how to receive it.

```
//Output
running
Got some data etc
Finished


// In Component
  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {
    console.log('running');
    this.imageService.test(()=>{
      console.log('Finished');
    });
  }
  

// In a service
  test(CallBack: { (callback: any): void; (): void; }) {
     this.httpClient.post('http://localhost/api/gallery/buildGallery', this.postData)
   .subscribe((data)=>{
       console.log('Got some data',data);
       CallBack(data);
     },(error)=>{
       console.log('error');
      CallBack ();
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try like this :

```js
Component :

constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {
  console.log('running');
  this.imageService.test(...).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

```js
Service :

test(postData: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost/api/gallery/buildGallery', postData);
}
```

---

Here is some examples of [How to handle errors on subscribe](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/). It should look like :

```js
this.imageService.test(...).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log('Success : ', res);
  },
  error => {
    console.error('Error :', error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Got a question though. How do I handle an error? Say no data comes back for instance. I know it always should, but what if it doesn't? There is a lot to typescript. I have only been learning for about 3 days.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Great ! I edited my post :) If the answer really helped you, I would appreciate to mark it as resolved.

Comment: Yes this solves my problem. Sorry upvoted you and forgot to click the tick. Done now. I am starting to like Angular better than Angularjs. It's just there are some difference I haven't quite worked out yet

Comment: Oh god, The AngularJS framework is on Long Term Support ("LTS") until December 31, 2021. After that date Google will no longer update AngularJS to fix security, browser compatibility, or jQuery issues. Happy coding on Angular